# package explorer horizontally to vertically eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

I have kind of stupid question, but well I can't find the solution.

My menu "Package Explorer" was always on the left side of eclipse next to my workpart. Dont know when it changed to horizontal view. How can I set it to vertical again?

Answer (score 4):

Click and hold the window from the title and drag it to the desired place.

Answer (score 1):

you can reset to default perspective to restore your default layout:

window->Reset Perspective...